# string concatenation and yielding block based on if modifier

Tags: ruby

This is a purely ruby syntax question, even though it's in the context of Rails.

I have a method which accepts a block and converts it to proc object in its definition:

```
def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)
  if block_given?
    yield(block) +
  end
  form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
end
```

The block is a piece of html as a string and I want to concatenate it with form.label which itself is returned as a string of html. However, I only want to concatenate the two if the block is given.

The above produces syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

Using the if modifier also does not work:

```
def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)
  yield(block) + if block_given?
  form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
end
```

I might also later need to do something like this (in which case I concatenate 3 strings conditionally):

```
def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)
  form.label(options[:errors], class: "control-label required") +
  yield(block) + if block_given?
  form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
end
```

What is the best approach to concatenate a block with a string when the block may be optional?

One solution I thought of after asking the question is maybe this:

```
   def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)     
     if block_given?
       content = capture(&block)
     else
       content = ""
     end

     form.label(form.object.errors[attr]) + content + form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
   end
```

Comment: Why do you have the arguments `attr` and `options`, considering that they are not used? Is `form_label` a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings like that. The line `yield(block) +` isn't a complete line. That's why you're getting the errors. Here are two possible fixes:

```
def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)
  if block_given?
    return yield(block) + form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
  end
  form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
end
```

Or this

```
def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)
  content = ''
  if block_given?
    content = yield(block)
  end
  content + form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an error because you left a dangling `+` inside your if block

You could do something like this

```
def wrapper(form, attr, options = {}, &block)
  res = block_given? ? yield(block) : ""
  res + form.label(form_label, class: "control-label")
end
```